# Is this possible to change the keywords 2,3,4 colors for custom language in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, keyword, color-scheme, file-type

Hey is it possible to change the keywords for 2,3 and 4 in a custom language without making a plugin ?
[image: edit file type window]

I know I can do it for keyword 1 here :
[image]

But there are no option for other keywords. For example keyword 2 is pink : 
[image]

Comment: No, but you can try the TextMate bundles support instead: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/textmate.html.

Comment: It seems like my intellij version doesn't support the Textmate bundle plugin

Comment: All the current IDE versions support it.

Comment: @CrazyCoder well it doesn't appear when I search it https://imgur.com/a/jX6Nj84, and the plugin website is down for me

Comment: It's a bundled plug-in: https://i.imgur.com/M1Nk2Qk.png.

Comment: I see thanks. Is creating a textmate bundle easier than an intellij plugin (there is no bundle for redcode which has just like 20 different keywords/operators) ? Like I just want 2 type of command with 2 different color

Comment: Yes, it's easier than a plug-in.